# Displaying an image from HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

A .Net Core web app is using HttpClient to retrieve an image (I think?). If a browser using those end points, I think it will load an image. I can't check it as the end points require authorization through the header which cannot be done on browsers.

```
string endpoint = "somelink";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(endpoint);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "image/jpeg");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "somekey");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
Stream receiveStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

Console.WriteLine(response);
Console.WriteLine(readStream.ReadToEnd());
```

I get the output as:

[image]

On the Server side, I am giving a byte array as content so it should be inside there somewhere. I am not sure how use this information to display the image.

```
[HttpGet, Route("some link")]
      public HttpResponseMessage GetQRCodeGeneratedForPackagedDrug(string id, bool returnSSLLink = false)
        {
            return GetQRCodeGenerated(id);
        }

    private HttpResponseMessage GetQRCodeGenerated(string drugId)
    {
        Stopwatch totalStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        totalStopwatch.Start();


        try
        {
            QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
            QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(drugId, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
            QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
            Bitmap qrCodeImageBitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            byte[] imgData = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(qrCodeImageBitMap, typeof(byte[]));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData);
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
            return this.Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new WebServicesException(ClaimsIdentityHelper.GetServiceCallID(), ex, callContext.CallID);
        }
        finally
        {
            totalStopwatch.Stop();
            Logger.LogResponseTracking(totalStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, ClaimsIdentityHelper.GetServiceCallID(), this.GetType().ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40794275/return-jpeg-image-from-asp-net-core-webapi before? It looks very similar to your issue.

Comment: If you have source code for the server-side, you'll need to include it in your question as it looks like that is where your issue lies.

Comment: @421 I am unable to use PhysicalFile or File for some reason on the server side even though I am in a controller context. Let me try to upload some of it.

Comment: `HttpResponseMessage` is not a valid return type for ASP.NET Core MVC. The response will be serialized and returned as json. Why can't you just `return File(stream, contentType);`?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I tried doing that but I get errors. I have updated the question.

Comment: Which error? Please be specific inside your question.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Sorry I do not have access to the code right now, but basically I get the error: Non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma which is weird because that error would appear if you are not in a controller according to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936628/non-invocable-member-file-cannot-be-used-like-a-method-while-generating-report?rq=1