# C# display first pdf from directory -> browser -> print : issue with return File( error

Tags: c#, pdf, browser, printing

return File(**File underlined in red**)... difficulty debugging. VS2017 ide. I'm trying to have the scripting in the code-behind of the page, to be able to see the relationships of namespace, class, methods.

I tried using System.Web.MVC per [Non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method while generating Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936628/non-invocable-member-file-cannot-be-used-like-a-method-while-generating-report) but it doesn't resolve the issue, and it causes other issues... which may exist, but I haven't been able to debug yet.

I appreciate the additional search for similar questions when posting my question. I reviewed them, and wasn't able to glean a workable solution.  Anyway, Thanks in advance for any help on this.

//return File(pdfPath, "application/pdf", pdfFile); issue on this line below

```
`//Default.aspx.cs

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mime;
//using System.Web.MVC

namespace BusSched
{
public partial class _Main : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton LinkButton;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {  }

public class CustomFile
{
public byte[] FileContents { get; set; }
public string ContentType { get; set; }
public string FileName { get; set; }
}

public static String ShowPdf(string directoryPath, string outputFileName)
{
var pdfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.pdf");

//ContentType ct = new ContentType("application/pdf");
string pdfFile;
string pdfPath;
GetPdf(pdfFiles[0]);

void GetPdf(string fileName)
{
Uri uri = new System.Uri(fileName);
pdfFile = uri.Segments.Last();
var noLastSegment = string.Format("{0}://{1}", uri.Scheme, uri.Authority);
for (int i = 0; i < uri.Segments.Length - 1; i++)
{
noLastSegment += uri.Segments[i];
}
pdfPath = noLastSegment;
}
return File(pdfPath, "application/pdf", pdfFile); // <---
}

class Response
{
internal static void AppendHeader(string v1, string v2)
{
throw new NotImplementedException();
}
}
}
}

//Default.aspx
protected void Repeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) {
var lb = (LinkButton) e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton");
var dirVal = lb.Text;

if (e.CommandName == "LBHandler") {
if (dirVal != null) {
String pdfPath = "M:/M_drive/Projects/PDF_Test/";
BusSched._Main.ShowPdf(pdfPath,"22-070113.pdf");
}
}
}`
```